# Creating a hamburger navigation bar with Semantic UI on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar, haml, semantic-ui

I'm attempting to create a hamburger menu with Semantic UI on Rails, but it isn't working. On the navigation bar, I have the logo Recipeazy, and then I have 3 items,  Home, About Us, and Settings, and then I have 2 buttons: Create a new Recipe, and Sign out. (If the user is not signed in, there are only 2 buttons, Login and Sign up. I used ruby to make the if else statement). I tried doing what someone did over [here](http://ehkoo.github.io/semantic-ui-examples/navbar/) but it did not work. So then I tried inspecting Semantic UI's webpage's side bar and still did not work. I would like to stick with Semantic UI's sidebar though. Here is my code:

application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Recipeazy
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    %link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css"}
    %link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"}

    = csrf_meta_tags
%body
    %div.ui.fixed.inverted.main.menu
        %div.ui.container
            %a.launch.icon.item
                %i.content.icon
            .wrapper.clearfix
                %div.brand.item
                    #logo= link_to "Recipeazy", root_path
                    %nav
                    - if user_signed_in?
                        %div.item
                            = link_to root_path do
                                %i.fa.fa-home
                                Home
                        %div.item
                            = link_to about_path do
                                %i.fa.fa-book
                                About Us
                        %div.item
                            = link_to edit_user_registration_path do
                                %i.fa.fa-cog
                                Settings
                        %div.item
                            = link_to new_post_path, class: "button" do
                                %i.fa.fa-plus
                                Add Recipe
                        %div.item
                            = link_to destroy_user_session_path, class:"button", method: :delete do
                                %i.fa.fa-sign-out
                                Sign Out
                    - else
                        %item
                            = link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: "button"
                        %item
                            = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "button"

    %p.notice= notice
    %p.alert= alert
    .wrapper
        = yield
```

I think that the Semantic UI is working because I already used it to style the buttons on my other pages.